# why is my column index not sorted properly?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sort such a dataframe(df) and I want to sort the columns by index on ascending order so I type in:

```
df_sorted=df.sort_index(axis=1,level=int)
```

however it returns me the order like this... isn't the column should be ordered in int like 1,2,3,....115?

```
1    10  100  101    102    103  104 ...   94  95  96  97  98  99  Unnamed: 0
0    0   0    0    0    0    0    0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0           1
1    0   0    0    0    0    0    0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0           2
2    0   0    0    0    0    0    0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0           3
3    0   0    0    0    0    0    0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0           4
4    0   0    0    0    0    0    0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0           5
..  ..  ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..         ...
111  0   0    0    0    0    0    0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0         110
112  0   0    0    0    0    0    0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0         111
113  0   0    0    0    0    0    0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0         112
114  0   0    0    0    0    0    0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0         113
115  0   0    0    0    0    0    0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0         114
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your index type, it should be object

```
df.columns.dtype
dtype('O')
```

We need to convert to numeric

```
out = df.iloc[:,pd.to_numeric(df.columns,errors='coerce').argsort()]
```

Or

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(object)
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

With another package

```
import natsort as ns 

out = df.iloc[:,ns.index_natsorted(df.columns)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `natsort`.

Install with:

```
python -m pip install natsort
```

```
import pandas as pd
from natsort import natsorted


data= {
'10': [1,2],
'111': [4,4],
'100': [2,3],
'1000': [6,6],
'102': [0,5],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.reindex(natsorted(df.columns), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   10  100  102  111  1000
0   1    2    0    4     6
1   2    3    5    4     6
```